# append and remove elements on upcount and downcount

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

I've a question on the `jQuery UI Slider` widget. What I intend to do is, that on every upcounting value the slider appends me an image in a div:

```
$("#divOne").slider({
        range: "min",
        min: 1,
        max: 10,

       slide: function (event, ui) {
           console.log(ui.value);

           if(ui.value == 1) {
              $('#divOne').append('<img class="linkimg" src="img/link/zwei.png">');
           }
           if(ui.value == 2) {
              $('#divOne').append('<img class="linkimg" src="img/link/drei.png">');
           }
           if(ui.value == 3) {
              $('#divOne').append('<img class="linkimg" src="img/link/eins.png">');
                     }
       },

           change: function (event, ui) {
              //alert('Stopped at ' + ui.value);
           }  
});
```

works good so far.

The problem is, I want to remove the elements if I'm then downcounting but then if I cross one number it of course appends again, so I guess compare the value in that if-statement is wrong.

Does anyone of you has a hint? Cheers

**EDIT:** I have made an image to show what I want to do [CLICK](http://i.imagebanana.com/img/tijkus5l/unbenannbt.jpg)

Comment: You should show/hide instead of append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume placing all the images in html

```
/* cache collection of images*/
var $images= $("#divOne img")
$("#divOne").slider({            

       slide:function(e,ui){
            if( ui.value !== $images.filter(':visible').length){
                $images.hide().slice( 0, ui.value).show();
            }
       }

});
```

What this does is track number visible vs slider value.... if they don't match it hides all and shows the ones that match slider.

If you have a large number... this should be upgraded to track direction of slider and only modify affected images to improve performance

Comment: far simpler than all the other stuff mentioned too. WOrked right out of the box sounds like

Comment: one question left, to make it a bit "smoother" I tried to replace the hides and shows with fadeIn/Out. Of course it fires the fadeIn again, any idea how to handle this?

Comment: problem I see with that idea is speed of user moving slider as well as fading out ones that don't need to be. WOuld have to rewrite using `stop()` as well as add a tracking counter. If you can create a demo in jsfiddle.net...even just using other html tags than img...I'll see what I can do. Should be able to make it work though

Comment: @charlietfl Instead of hiding and showing the actual img elements, I imagine it would be far more performant to set the parent div's overflow to hidden and then manipulate the width. Of course, it's still much faster to do everything in CSS...

Comment: here's a starter on how to go about animating a bit.....it's buggy, but I don't have time to do more  http://plnkr.co/edit/WM2QHVBOsvOOSSnH5FiL Will give you an idea how it would work

Comment: @bvukelic might work...except for would see partial images during animation. Not sure what OP wants...sounds a bit unusual to me though rather than just manipulating individual images

Comment: @charlietfl The rationale is that you want to reduce the number of nodes you have to manipulate in the callback. Also, I wouldn't animate the change in width. Not sure if OP wants a smooth animated hiding and showing, but there is no partial showing of images if it's not animated. Then again, if OP wishes to use animation, I think CSS transitions are a much better solution and allow for progresive enchancement in modern browsers without degrading performance.

Comment: @bvukelic I don't think dealing with a lot of images here....at least my assumption. Also by caching jQuery selector not traversing DOM much. Agree about transitions...however I provided a very workable solution that anyone is free to expand on. It avoided a lot of extra work like changing file names, writing unique classes and did exactly what OP asked for

Comment: @charlietfl Easy there, nobody is saying that your solution is bad. Just discussing possible optimizations. I've dealt with quite a few weird situations on mobile devices and sometimes silly optimization make a big difference, that's all.

Comment: @charlietfl yeah your thought was right, your second fiddle is pretty much exactly what I intend to do. Theres only one thing I curious about, is it possible to avoid the fadeOut at the beginning, I mean I dont want the user sees the images before he turns the slider. And at your fiddle I see the images at the beginning. Despite that I appreciate your help alot and thanks!

Comment: @bvukelic and thanks as well for your effort I appreciate that. The problem is, that for example your html solution isnt crossbrowser compatible and it refreshes the picture on release, not immediatly. Anyways I'm someone who uses jquery for every single manipulation, even if its possible to do with css. Might be wrong, but at least I have a lil bit more knowledge about jQuery than css an all its pseudo-classes and so on.

Comment: @supersize I know it's not cross-browser. It's just an example. When you show your image or how you implement the slider itself is entirely your problem. The CSS was the focus of the fiddle. edit: or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @supersize For example, if you put the callback function from my fiddle and use it as a slide callbak in your jQuery UI slider, it will do what you want.

Comment: yes regarding fadeout at beginning. I really hadn't gotten as far as would have liked by adding css etc. I would set to opacity 0 and use slider value to immediately set using css the ones neeed. I hinged startup from slider value...If know it will always be 1 on start....just set first child opposite of hide animation

Comment: @bvukelic  trying too hard brother!

Answer (score 1):

First change the image names to match the values. E.g., `1.png`, `2.png`. Then you can:

```
var i, maxVal = ui.value, html='';
for (i = 1; i <= maxVal; i += 1) {
  html += '<img src="img/' + i + '.png';
}
$('#divOne').html(html);
```

EDIT: But in general a better approach is to have all images in the container and then construct a stylesheet that would map classes that match values to appropriate state. E.g.:

```
<div class="score[X]"> <!-- where `[X]` will be the actual value of the ui.value -->
   <img class="val1" src="1.png">
   <img class="val2" src="2.png">
   <img class="val3" src="3.png">
</div>
```

In css:

```
.score1 .val2 { display: none; }
.score1 .val3 { display: none; }
....
```

Or some other variation of the above.

EDIT:

Example fiddle with a slightly different approach for CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/gwQAW/

EDIT2:

And version with HTML5 slider: http://jsfiddle.net/gwQAW/2/ (sorry, no time for jQuery UI right now)

Comment: thanksk for your answer, but I guess I do explain myself a lil bit bad so I made an img of what I want to do:
http://i.imagebanana.com/img/tijkus5l/unbenannbt.jpg

Comment: @supersize You explained well. Maybe I haven't explained my answer well enough. Note that it uses `$('#divOne').html()` instead of `$('#divOne').append()` so it will always clear existing images and rebuild images from scratch. It should work. But as noted in the edit, CSS-based solution would be better.

Comment: ah got your idea, seems very elegent to me. Just to be clear, you mean I'm removing and adding the classes on the specific value? like `if(ui.value == 1) { $('#divOne').addClass('score2')};`?

Comment: @supersize Basically yes. I'd probably add a class that is calculated from the `ui.value` like `'score' + (ui.value + 1)`.

Comment: @supersize Also, if the DIV has no other classes, I think just overriding the entire class with `$('#divOne')[0].className = 'score...'`. You know, to avoid having to remove classes and all that...

Comment: sorry but I'm not that into pure JS. Exactly that snippet works?

Comment: You can use this instead: `$("#divOne").attr('class', ...);`

Comment: there's simpler ways that don't require renaming files, or replacing the full html

Comment: @charlietfl The CSS solution I suggested also doesn't require renaming files. I just used different filenames for brevity and lack of knowledge in German language. :)

Comment: @bvukelic haha you should learn some german! anyways, unfortunenately I cant get it to work. Would it be to cheeky if I ask you to edit your answer and write the css, html markup and js for your css solution?

Comment: @supersize Sure, I'll fiddle something down. Will probably give you a simplified version without jQuery UI, though.

Comment: @bvukelic charlietfls version works pretty well for me, don't want you to make effort. anyways, if youre almost finished with it, Im looking forward to see it without jquery UI but I dont see a disadvantage to use jqueryUI

Comment: @supersize Updated answer with CSS. Sorry the CSS isn't very good. I usually use SASS, but didn't know if that'd work for you.

Comment: @supersize Also updated to use HTML5 slider (works on Chrome) so you can see how it works with a slider interface of a kind. Should work the same way with jQuery UI. http://jsfiddle.net/gwQAW/1/